# Searching for keywords & Entering Text

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

I am very green when it comes to VBA for Excel. However, I have read as much as I can on VBA and still cannot fathom how to write this code. One of the problems that I have is with the syntax itself.

Currently, I have a spreadsheet where the information is not constant and I want to be able to search this spreadsheet for specific words and then Excel to move one cell to the right and enter in a some text. If the specific words are not there, then I want VBA to do nothing and continue searching for the next words.

So, here's what's in my head, I just don't know how to write it out in the correct syntax:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SortAndLabel()

'Here is where I get lost as far as syntax goes so I will just type in what I'm wanting it to do...

Search the current worksheet for "12345 Total"

If "12345 Total" is not found then Do Nothing

Else

'Move 1 cell to the right
ActiveCell.Offset(0,1)

'Then enter in the following text (I don't know the proper syntax for this)...
Enter text "Electric"

End If
```

I would appreciate any help that you can provide.

Comment: Start by using the macro recorder to generate the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on following code.

```
Sub FindSub()
Dim fng As Range
Dim fText As String

fText = "12345 Total"

    Set fng = Sheet1.Cells.Find(fText)

        If Not fng Is Nothing Then
            fng.Offset(0, 1) = "Electric"
        Else
            MsgBox "No match found."
        End If
Set fng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Harun24HR. This fixed my issue. I did have one question... How could I have VBA "Do Nothing" instead of showing me a message box stating that "No match found". Previous things that I've read online state that I should just put "Do Nothing", but that always seems to error out for me.

Comment: Then just use if statement. remove else part.